# References section overlapping for \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, ieeetran, ieee-style

I'm currently experiencing an issue where my references overlap using the `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`

This file is based on a template from Overleaf.

I have created an example to demonstrate problem:

[link to .bib file](https://pastebin.com/uPJtftzV)

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\ifCLASSINFOpdf
 \usepackage{graphicx}
  \graphicspath{{./img/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png}
\else
\fi
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi

\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Keywords}

\hyphenation{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

\title{title}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{block\_n}
\IEEEauthorblockA{block\_a}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  abstract
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
  keywords;
  keywords; 
  keywords; 
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{foobar}

\end{document}
```

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Your bibfile is riddled with errors, your code produces some pdf, but it does not compile fully. I suggest fix your bib file, it might fix your problem altogether.

Comment: ah, your bib file is fine, it just has urls in it :) I've added an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bib file has html and url addresses that contain characters that would confuse the compiler.

Luckily the solution is simple: [`\usepackage{url}`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) sorts this out allowing you to use urls in your bib and text.